# How to send username and password for authentication in rtk Query for authentication

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

```
export const authCheckApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'authCheckApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4001',
  }),

  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    checkAuth: builder.query({
      query: (username, password) => ({
        url: `/user/login/`,
        method: 'POST',
        body: { email: username, password: password },
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
      }),
    }),

    //endPoints end braces below
  }),
  //main end below
});
```

Comment: export const authCheckApi=createApi({
    reducerPath:'authCheckApi',
    baseQuery:fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl:'http://localhost:4001',
   
    }),

Answer (score 2):

It's kinda missing the question, but it seems you are almost there - but `query` only takes one argument from user input, so you'll have to put both username and password into the first argument.

```js
        query:({ username, password })=>({
            
            url:`/user/login/`,
            method:'POST',
            body:{email:username,password:password},
            headers:{
                'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',                   
            },

        })
```